# problem in working on Date

Tags: java, android, datetime, date, android-2.1-eclair

```
I want to convert String to date object I used this code to convert

  try{

            SimpleDateFormat parse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");
            String dateTime = "1996-10-7T4:50:00Z";
        Date parsed = parse.parse(dateTime);
            System.out.println("formatted: " + formatter.format(parsed));
            }
            catch(ParseException e){
            System.out.println("Caught " + e);
            }

output:



I need value of date object to be **1996-10-7T4:50:00Z** as it as the given string.
```

but above code produce date object :Mon Oct 07 04:50:00 PDT 1996

Comment: Your code sample gives me `1996-10-07T04:50:00Z` - not what you encountered. Must be something else.

Comment: +1 for all!  You use a `Date` object to hold a specific instance of time.  You use a `SimpleDateFormatter` to take a `Date` and display it as you would like to (or to parse a string representation of a `Date` into an actual `Date` object).

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

Use the same object to parse and format.

Comment: A Date object has no notion of representation.  That's formatting.  You're not thinking about java.util.Date properly.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this, you will get your answer for sure,

[SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

When I ran the above code, I received this output:

> formatted: 1996-10-07T04:50:00Z

Comment: formatted is a string object ....I want date object to be 1996-10-07T04:50:00Z But above code produce Mon Oct 07 04:50:00 PDT 1996

Comment: The `Date` object doesn't have a representation that you can manipulate.  That is why you use the `SimpleDateFormatter`, it has the ability to change the `String` representation to something more desireable.

Answer (score 1):

Your Date object is not formatted in itself. The formatter does the job.
When I run your code I obtain:

```
formatted: 1996-10-07T04:50:00Z
```

Which is fine.

**EDIT**: btw ***duffymo*** is right, below: you don't need to have two distinct formatters.

Comment: formatted is a string object ....I want date object to be 1996-10-07T04:50:00Z But above code produce Mon Oct 07 04:50:00 PDT 1996

Comment: No, look at the line I copied: "formatted: 1996-10-07T04:50:00Z" comes from the `System.out.println()` of your code. `Date.toString()` will never give you the formatted result you want as a `Date` is actually a nothing more than a long integer number, so the need to use a formatter.

Comment: This is what we are all doing: your code is just fine! You have no other way than what you have done to obtain the result you need :)

Comment: Nothing needs to be done, except to correct your erroneous understanding of the object Date.